# Text to blob и обратно

Tags: php, mysql, python, python-2.x

Здравствуйте. Существует 2 части проекта. 1 часть написана на python, она должна переводить строку в hex/blob/binary (не знаю что лучше подходит для хранения hex). И записывает это в mysql. Функция с помощью которой str -> hex

```
def strbin(s):
   return ''.join(format(ord(i),'0>8b') for i in s)
```

Поле в таблице пока имеет тип LONGBLOB (может подскажете что лучше)
И так следующая часть на php.

```
 $mysqli->query("SELECT CONVERT(response USING utf8) FROM tablename WHERE id = 1 INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/test.txt'");
```

Но вот беда, на выходе hex или просто какие-то непонятные символы. Я пока не понимаю в каком месте я ошибся, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: вам *не нужно байтовую строку* (`str` тип (`bytes` на Питоне 3)) *никак преобразовывать*, чтобы в базу данных положить (базы данных замечательно двоичные данные (blob) умеют хранить). Если на входе текст (в Питоне используйте `unicode` тип (`str` на Питоне 3)), то опять таки не нужно в "01"-строку преобразовывать -- mysql умеет хранить (BMP) Юникодные символы напрямую.

Comment: похожий вопрос: [blob/hex/binary to str python](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/549786/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю можно ли сделать в чистом SQL(MySQL), но с PHP можно попробовать так:

```
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT response FROM tablename WHERE id = 1");
$obj = $res->fetch_object();


$symbs = str_split($obj->response, 8);                                                                              

$toWrite = ""
foreach ($symbs as $symb) {                                                                       
    $toWrite .= chr(bindec($symb));                                                                            
} 

// Write to the file.
```

Выполняються действия зеркальные питону.

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно!