# blob/hex/binary to str python

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

Здравствуйте. Конвертирую str в blob/hex/binary с помощью функции:

```
def strbin(s):
   return ''.join(format(ord(i),'0>8b') for i in s)
```

Подскажите функцию которая бы действовала наоборот (зеркально) этой.

Comment: Можно классикой https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

Comment: related: [Convert binary to ASCII and vice versa](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7396849/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы сконвертировать "01"-строку битов в соответствующую байтовую строку:

```
import binascii

def bytes_from_bits(bits):
    """'0101011100100101' -> b'W%'"""
    return int2bytes(int(bits, 2))

def int2bytes(i):
    """22309 -> b'W%'"""
    hex_string = '%x' % i
    n = len(hex_string)
    return binascii.unhexlify(hex_string.zfill(n + (n & 1)))
```

Чтобы сконвертировать байты в соответствующую битовую строку (ascii-строка, представляющая число в двоичной системе):

```
def bytes_to_bits(bytestring):
    """b'W%' -> '0101011100100101'"""
    bits = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(bytestring), 16))[2:]
    return bits.zfill(8 * ((len(bits) + 7) // 8))
```

Comment: При декодировании появляются 2 переноса строки на месте 1 (в исходном тексте)

Comment: @LorDo: вы возможно на Windows где перенос строки это два байта: `b'\r\n'`. Если вы думаете, что какая-то функция не работает, то укажите какая именно функция (их 3 в ответе) и приведите минимальный пример: что на входе (ввиде строковой константы такой как `'10001111'`), что функция возвращает (не словами описывайте, а результат покажите такой как: `'\x8f'`), и что вы вместо этого хотите получить (опять таки в виде `repr(result)`). Если вы пытаетесь текстовый файл в биты и обратно преобразовать, то это отдельный вопрос (кодировка, `'\n' <-> os.linesep` итд).

Comment: Я пытаюсь преобразовать в биты и обратно длинную строку в которой присутствуют переносы строки (\r и \n). Вот примерочная "строка" : http://pastebin.com/zniCPrSy. Я ее перевожу в биты используя свою функцию в шапке вопроса (strbin). И получаю код http://pastebin.com/jsfmExMj Далее я пытаюсь первыми 2мя функциями из вашего поста преобразовать обратно в текст (точнее bytes_from_bits) и получаю вот такой вот выход http://pastebin.com/tBjGEpi8. Как видите с переносом строки что-то не то.

Comment: не нужно на pastebin ничего выкладывать. Я просил **минимальный** пример такой как: *«`bytes_from_bits('0101011100100101')` возвращает `'W%'`, а я хотел `'здесь желаемый результат'` вместо этого»*

Comment: Да бог его знает как привести тут минимальный пример чтобы было понятно, выложил уже на пастенбин, там наглядно видно проблему с переносами строк.

Comment: @LorDo: Запустите `python` должно появиться `>>>` (приглашение). Сделайте копи-паст (мышкой выделить/скопировать/вставить код из моего ответа). Наберите `bytes_from_bits('101010101010')`, где вместо `101010101010` подставьте что хотите, посмотрите на результат -- если результат не тот какой вам хочется, то скопируйте из консоли в комментарий (если не знаете как код в комментарий добавить, нажмите  на ссылку "справка" -- под кнопкой "комментировать"). Если всё ещё не ясно как копировать, попробуйте в [чате спросить](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com)