# binascii.Error: Odd-length string что делать?

Tags: python, hex

и так, я читаю hex код и теперь мне нужно декодировать этот код например: у меня есть hex код `68656c6c6f`а так же функция:

```
def to_text(h):
    return binascii.unhexlify(h)
```

но при передаче в функцию вышеуказанного hex-кода, то вызывается

```
binascii.Error: Odd-length string
```

при этом в онлайн переводчиках все работает что делать?

Comment: Покажите участок кода, в котором вызываете эту функцию.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Кодирование текста в произвольный двоичный код и обратно. Пример: "А" <-> "01100011"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/715681/23044)

Comment: Мне `binascii.unhexlify("68656c6c6f")` выдает результат `b'hello' ` (Python 3.6.1) Значит, что вы как параметр задали что-то другое, с нечётным числом букв.

Answer (score 1):

`unhexlify()` ожидает, что каждый байт представлен двумя шестнадцатиричными цифрами, поэтому для байтов со значением меньше 16<sub>10</sub> (10<sub>16</sub>) следует слева нолик добавить. См. [blob/hex/binary to str python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/549786/23044)